# How to make an element's background-color a little darker using CSS

Tags: html, css, background-color

I have the following CSS for a button:

```
.Button {
  background-color: #somehex;
}
```

When the user hovers over the button, I want the `background-color` to be a little darker. I have tried changing opacity, which didn't work, and currently am doing it this way:

```
.Button:hover {
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
  background-color: #ALittleDarkerHex;
}
```

While this process works, it is really tedious because I have to manually look for a darker version of the color I am working with. I was wondering if there was an easier way to darken the `background-color` of a button using CSS.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Add a dark layer on the top of it using `background-image`. This method keeps your text visible in the same color while changing only the background.

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.button:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(0 0 0/40%) 0 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="button"> some text </div>
<div class="button" style="background-color:lightblue;"> some text </div>
<div class="button" style="background-color:green;"> some text </div>
<div class="button" style="background-color:grey;"> some text </div>
```

To have a transition:

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(#0000, rgb(0 0 0/40%)) top/100% 800%;
  background-color: red;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover {
  background-position: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="button"> some text </div>
<div class="button" style="background-color:lightblue;"> some text </div>
<div class="button" style="background-color:green;"> some text </div>
<div class="button" style="background-color:grey;"> some text </div>
```

Another idea with mix-blend-mode:

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(0 0 0/40%) 0 0);
  background-blend-mode: lighten;
}

.button:hover {
  background-blend-mode: darken;
}
```

```html
<div class="button"> some text </div>
<div class="button" style="background-color:lightblue;"> some text </div>
<div class="button" style="background-color:green;"> some text </div>
<div class="button" style="background-color:grey;"> some text </div>
```

You can also consider a big inset box-shadow and you will also have the ability to add transition:

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax inset rgb(0 0 0/var(--o,0%));
  transition: .4s;
}

.button:hover {
  --o: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="button"> some text </div>
<div class="button" style="background-color:lightblue;"> some text </div>
<div class="button" style="background-color:green;"> some text </div>
<div class="button" style="background-color:grey;"> some text </div>
```

Comment: With `background-position`, how to account for a thick border on the button? Looks like some offset needed?

Comment: This actually seems to work well (buttons with border): `background-position: calc(100% + 2px);`, where 2px is border width.

Comment: You should add `color-mix` to this list! Maybe also [relative colors](https://blog.jim-nielsen.com/2021/css-relative-colors/)

Comment: @ZachSaucier to use color-mix I need to have the color as a variable but here the input is a color applied to background-color

Comment: For people searching, I'm betting most would be helped by knowing of its existinence

Answer (score 13):

This is one way you can do it

```css
.button {
  background-color: red;
}

.button:hover {
    filter: brightness(60%);
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Button</button>
```

Anything above `brightness(100%)` will increase the brightness and anything less will make it darker.

Comment: I like this idea but changing the brightness also dims the white text that I have inside the button. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: This method is super quick and effective if you just want to go with the colours you already have for the button and don't want to rejiggle everything. I don't mind that it darkens the text too. I just want to let users know that they are hovering.

Comment: One downside of this technique is that it changes the text/font color as well.

Answer (score 4):

You may consider using [HSL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/hsl()) color values, which can better meet your needs. The HSL color model is more easily read and understood by humans compared to the Hex color code ([`#FF0033`](https://fromkato.com/color/ff0033)).

> HSL color values are specified with: `hsl(hue, saturation, lightness)`.

```css
div {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  color: white;
}

.Button {
  --hue: 348;
  --saturation: 100%;
  --lightness: 50%;
  background-color: hsl(var(--hue), var(--saturation), var(--lightness));
}

.Button.dark:hover {
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
  --lightness: 40%;
  /* 20% dark */
}

.Button.light:hover {
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
  --lightness: 80%;
  /* 20% light */
}
```

```html
<div class='Button dark'>PayPay</div>
<div class='Button light'>PayPay</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put pseudo element behind button content and modify its opacity on hover

```js
const colors = ['#052F5F','#005377','#06A77D','#D5C67A','#F1A208'];
const btn = document.querySelector('.Button');
btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  btn.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
});
```

```css
.Button {
  background-color: #F1A208;
  color:#fff;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px 22px;
  cursor:pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.Button:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index:0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  transition: .2s ease;
}
.Button span {
  position: relative;
  z-index:1;
}
.Button:hover:before {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

```html
<button class="Button"><span>hover me</span></button>
```

Answer (score -2):

It is easier if you put background color a tint dark then add it to the hover function also add transitions to make it smooth you can either use the RGB or RGBA for the background color.

```html
<button class="button">button</button>

<style>
  .button {
    Border: none;
    Border-radius: 4px;
    Color: white;
    Cursor: pointer;
    Width: 86px;
    Height: 32x;
    Background-color: rgba(121, 82, 179);
    color:white
    transition:all 1s;
  }
  
  .button:hover {
    Background-color: rgba(114, 77, 170, 80);
  }
</style>
```

Comment: OP is asking for an easier way other than pasting darker color codes all over the place.