# Make SCSS background the same color, but transparent

Tags: css, sass

I'm making my own SCSS framework for colors, borders and such.

I'm trying to create a class which would make the current background color of an element more transparent. The color would be set like this:

```
$bg-red: FF0000;

.bg-red {
   background: $bg-red
}
```

I wonder if there is a way to add a class that could take the current background and just make it a bit more transparent, without rewriting the color everytime, because I would be dealing with hundreads of colors, something like this:

```
.bg-transparent-50{
   background: (currentBackground,  opacity: 50%)
}
```

I know I'm not using the right syntax but this is just for the sake of explanation of what I'm looking for, anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: you want to see what is behind or you want to make the color lighter?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I want to see what is actually behind, is there a way or can I only make it lighter? If so, how?

Comment: for lighter like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65297702/8620333 (change the black with white)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that the best way to do this is to store your color variables is using an `rgb` value, and then adjust the opacity in a `rgba` declaration of the color:

```scss
$bg-red: rgb(255, 0, 0);

.bg-red {
   background: $bg-red
}

.bg-red-50{
   background: rgba($bg-red, 0.5)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `rgba` in combination with CSS properties.

```css
div {
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}

.background {
  --background-opacity: 100;
  background-color: rgba(var(--background-color), var(--background-opacity));
}

.background.black {
  --background-color: 0, 0, 0;
}

.opacity-100 {
  --background-opacity: 0;
}

.opacity-80 {
  --background-opacity: 0.2;
}

.opacity-60 {
  --background-opacity: 0.4;
}

.opacity-40 {
  --background-opacity: 0.6;
}

.opacity-20 {
  --background-opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="black background opacity-100"> 100% opacity </div>
<div class="black background opacity-80"> 80% </div>
<div class="black background opacity-60"> 60% </div>
<div class="black background opacity-40"> 40% </div>
<div class="black background opacity-20"> 20% </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no dedicated CSS property (like 'background-opacity').

You can simulate the effect with a background-image defined as a linear gradient over rgba values (ie. color tuples with transparency) on top of the background.

The gradient effect is cancelled by specifying a point interval:

```css
.bg-red {
    background: red;
}
.bg-transparent-50 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5));
}
```

```html
<p>
    <div class="bg-red"                   style="width: 200px; height: 50px;">Opaque background</div>
    <div class="bg-red bg-transparent-50" style="width: 200px; height: 50px;">Semi-transparent background</div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution for your use case is to use a pseudo (before/after) element. You'd be able to assign both a background-color and an opacity to it individually.